# Unable to call or transact with Rinkeby contract using Remix

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, metamask, rinkeby

I am very new to Solidity and I just managed to deploy a very simple contract to Rinkeby. However, for some reason I am unable to call or interact with it using Remix. Does anyone know whats wrong?

I have compiled the same contract on remix, changed my environment to Inject Web3 and created an instance by pasting the contract address to the At Address field, but when I try to call it or transact with it nothing happens!

[image: Unable to interact]

Comment: Did you wait long enough for the transaction to confirm? It worked for me.

Comment: It was an issue with my chrome browser. Works fine everywhere else.